# d3 Charts implementation in angular4

Tags: c#, html, angular, typescript, nvd3.js

I'm trying to implement bar chart in angular4 includes Html and TypeScript files as components Kindly guide me.

the bar should display number of increase in employees in months starting from current month in x axis

Comment: No luck with fusion charts could any one please help me on how to implement the stacked bar chart using d3 charts in angular4 typescript and Html

Answer (score 0):

You can use fusion charts for this..
https://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/column-bar-charts/

Comment: Thank you I will try implementing